# How to assign different template for each different subclasses of a Model based on their type

Tags: python, django

I have some models in my Django project which are subclasses of a base model class. example:

```
class A(Model):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass
```

for example in an online shopping I would have `Ebook`, `CD`, `Ball`. I could create `OneToOne` relationship with `OneToOneField` but I think in this case the user has to fill two forms, first he might fill a product field and then a form like ebook field.
Also I want to display the products in the database, weather it be Ebook or Movie or CD Player or any of other type, be listed in the product lists.
 So I decided to create the models this way. 
The problem is in the `view` part, where I have to decide which template I should show to fill in. nelow is the way I decided to solve this problem. But the problem with this solution is that I think it is not really useful as the number of products grow this will become a nightmare. I want to know how can I improve this solution.

I am new to python and Django. I searched a lot, and I couldn't find anything.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=self.__class__.__name__, editable=False)

    def getType(self):
        return self.product_type

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


class Book(Product):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Product.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.product_type == self.__class__.__name__

@login_required
def edit(request, product_id):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=service_id)
    except Product.DoesNotExist():
        return HttpResponseNotFound()

    if product.getType() == 'Ebook':
        product = product.ebook
        formObject = EbookForm
        template = 'products/edit_ebook.html'
    elif product.getType() == 'CD':
        product = product.host
        formObject = CdForm
        template = 'products/edit_cd.html'
    elif product.getType() == 'Dress':
        formObject = DressForm
        template = "products/edit_dress.html"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formObject(request.POST, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('product_index'))
    else:
        form = formObject(instance=product)

    return render(request, template, {'form' : form })
```

Comment: I would probably add them as attributes on the class.  I'm not sure how django models work, but in App Engine models, they'd need to be prefixed with an `_`.  e.g. `_formObject = EbookForm`

Comment: my eyes bleed when I see this: ` product.getType() == 'Ebook'` . Python is not Java ... http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html

Comment: @Oz123 I just read that article and found out why `getType()` annoyed you. Sorry about that :D as I said I am new to python

Comment: no need to apologize :-) that is why I gave a link. On the contrary, you learn from that. I should apologize for the harsh tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of all the `if` statements if you store the template name in your model, so you can just call `render(request, product.template, {'form': form})`.

So you would have a `CharField` called `template` on your `Product` model that you would populate with 'book', 'ebook', etc.

The principle behind this is called "[replace conditional with polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html)".

You should also consider using abstract base models, which is better for performance.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about storing template name in the models, But It is something odd to me, I think putting a view related (template in Django) information in models violates the rules of best practice